# How to do HBase partial Scan?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I have HBase table that contains around 10 Millions of records .
I have three question regarding HBase

1. How much time  scanning 10 Millions of records may take?
2. Should i go for HIVE HBase integration?
3. How to perform Partial Range scan if i prefix just one identifier like FL01 in every row ?

> 4294970043|1
>   column=cf:SegmentMultipleFundbDescription, timestamp=1478316937790,
>   value=  4294970043|1
>   column=cf:SegmentMultipleFundbDescription_languageId,
>   timestamp=1478316937790, value=505074  4294970043|1
>   column=cf:StatementTypeCode, timestamp=1478316937790, value=FTN 
>   4294970929|1                               column=cf:FFAction,
>   timestamp=1478316937790, value=I  4294970929|1
>   column=cf:FileName, timestamp=1478316937790,
>   value=Fundamental.FinancialLineItem.FinancialLineItem.ThirdPartyPrivate.FTN.1.2
>                                               016-07-15-2108.Full  4294970929|1                               column=cf:FilePartition,
>   timestamp=1478316937790, value=ThirdPartyPrivate  4294970929|1
>   column=cf:FilePartitionLocation, timestamp=1478316937790, value=FTN 
>   4294970929|1
>   column=cf:FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondary,
>   timestamp=1478316937790, value=  4294970929|1
>   column=cf:FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondaryId,
>   timestamp=1478316937790, value=  4294970929|1
>   column=cf:FinancialConceptGlobal, timestamp=1478316937790, value=METL 
>   4294970929|1
>   column=cf:FinancialConceptGlobalId, timestamp=1478316937790,
>   value=3015071

Answer (score 0):

HBASE will do a FTS unless and until you provide a start and stop row key. So if the identifier is part of a row key and if your row key is fixed, then you can try setting start and stop row key else try fuzzyfilter. Else if the identifier s not part of row key HBASE would do a FTS.

How much time it takes for a scan really depends on various factors like size of row key, how many CF, how many column qualifiers...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your keys are strings and that rows are returned as maps in an list, then your range scan should look something like the code below.

```
public List<Map<String,byte[]>> rangeFetch(String valueFrom, String valueTo, String[] columns, int maxrows) {
    ArrayList<Map<String,byte[]>> rst = new ArrayList<Map<String,byte[]>>();
    Scan scn = new Scan();
    scn.setStartRow(valueFrom.getBytes());
    scn.setStopRow (valueTo.getBytes());
    for (String colName : columns) {
        scn.addColumn(colName.getBytes());
    }
    ResultScanner rsc = null;
    int rowCount = 0;
    try {
        rsc = oTbl.getScanner(scn);
        for (Result res=rsc.next(); res!=null && rowCount<maxrows; res=rsc.next()) {
            Map<String,byte[]> row = new HashMap<String,byte[]>();
            for (String colName : columns) {
                KeyValue kvl = res.getColumnLatest("columnFamilyName".getBytes(), colName.getBytes());
                if (kvl!=null) {
                    if (kvl.getValue()!=null)
                        row.put(colName, kvl.getValue());
                }
            } // next
            rst.add(row);             
        } // next
    } finally {
        if (rsc!=null) rsc.close();
    }
    return rst;
}
```

then call it with

```
List<Map<String,byte[]>> results = yourObj.rangeFetch("FL01"+"000000", "FL01"+"999999", new String[]{"column1","column2","column3"}, 10000);
```